# CSS animation with fill-mode including transition not working in firefox properly

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

This works fine in Chrome, but won't in Firefox *(Here is the [online demo](http://codepen.io/fmtoffolo/pen/hxfkH))*:

**HTML**

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.box {
    background-color:blue;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transform: translate(-200px);
    animation-name: test;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

.box:hover {
    border-radius: 100%;
}

@keyframes test {
    100% {
        transform: translate(0px);
    }
}
```

If I remove the transition it works properly. It seems to be as if the transition, when activated by the on hover, removes the state set by the fill-mode: forwards.

Is there a way around it in firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I added a *keyframe* for the start point `0%` to get it to work:

```css
@keyframes test{
  0% {
     transform: translate(-200px);
  }
  100% {
      transform: translate(0px);
  }
}
```

Using the above, you could remove the `transform` property form the `.box` element.

Also, for the old versions of web browsers, consider using vendor prefixes such as `-webkit-` and `-moz-`, ... for the `@keyframes` and the other CSS3 properties.

<sub>PS: I tested the demo with FF 9.0.1. This issue may appear only in earlier versions of web browsers. In fact, web browsers try to fix your bad-coding but only the smarters will win!</sub>

**[WORKING DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eFkjf)**

### Update

In order to fix the rendering issue (when the animation starts) you need to change the `transition-property` from `all` to the specific properties you really want. (`border-radius` in this case):

```css
.box{
  animation-name: test;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transition: border-radius 0.25s ease;
}
```

The problem was because of the conflict between `animation` and `transition` for the `transform` property.

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FsrLd)**

Comment: I just tested this on ff and hover works but there is a jerking motion  before animation starts.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Thank you, I added the recommendation.

Comment: @fmtoffolo Since you're new to SO, If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as *accepted* by clicking on the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me on Firefox.  I put your example into JSFiddle, just as  you showed in your question, and it worked for me.

Comment: I tested this on FF on JSFIddle and it has the same problem